# btrfs found uncorrected disk errors, How can I find which files they are in?

Tags: btrfs

I ran btrfs scrub and got this:

```
scrub status for 57cf76da-ea78-43d3-94d3-0976308bb4cc
    scrub started at Wed Mar 15 10:30:16 2017 and finished after 00:16:39
    total bytes scrubbed: 390.45GiB with 28 errors
    error details: csum=28
    corrected errors: 0, uncorrectable errors: 28, unverified errors: 0
```

OK, I have good backups, and I would like to know **which files these 28 errors are in** so I can restore them from backup. That would save me a lot of time over wiping and restoring the whole disk.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/858237/finding-files-with-btrfs-uncorrectable-errors

Answer (score 9):

As @derobert pointed out in the comments, the path is to be found in the output of `dmesg` and looks like this:

```
[ 1202.714916] BTRFS warning (device dm-2): checksum error at logical 470470615040 on dev /dev/mapper/a-root, sector 923098608, root 2757, inode 1120855, offset 110592, length 4
096, links 1 (path: usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode)
```

And this command will print a list of the files to recover from backup:

```
dmesg| grep -e "BTRFS warning.*path:" | sed -e 's/^.*path\: //'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also be able to use `journalctl` if you're on a `systemd`-based system.

```
$ sudo journalctl --dmesg --grep 'checksum error'
```

See [my full response](https://superuser.com/a/1675438/321164) at the thread @Livius linked above.